Disable insecure MACs for sshd
I need to disable the following MACs on my OpenSSH server:
hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com, umac-128@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-512, hmac-sha1

I confgured /etc/ssh/sshd_config with:
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
MACs umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com

and restarted sshd, but the MACs to be disabled are still enabled:
$ sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -T | grep macs
macs umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1

According to the documentation I found on the web, specifying the MACs parameter in the configuration file should enable only the specified MACs, so I don't understand why also the unspecified ones are still active.
Version info: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u3, OpenSSL 1.1.1w

As an aside, why do you consider hmac-sha2-256 and hmac-sha2-512 insecure? Do you have a citation for that?

@larsks Thanks to your suggestion I found another MACs directive before the right one that actually screwed up everything, thanks! If you take care of writing an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

@jpiddle888 I just had these warnings from sshaudit.com:
hmac-sha2-256
Uses encrypt-and-MAC method. Score reduced by 1.
hmac-sha2-512
Uses encrypt-and-MAC method. Score reduced by 1.

I have moved my comment to an answer. Glad that helped out!

@NicolaMori Notice what the sample report on sshaudit.com says: "Encrypt-and-mac algorithms are theoretically weaker than encrypt-then-mac (etm) algorithms with respect to chosen plaintext attacks, chosen ciphertext attacks, and non-malleability" (my emphasis). You could say that about numerous encryption schemes. You're potentially limiting compatibility with other clients that try to connect. If it's your own server and you're not worried, then that's your call. The irony is that ETM MACs  (amongst other things) are a prerequisite for the Terrapin attack.

@jpiddle888 Yes it's a personal server and with my client I can connect also without the eam algorithms. Since it has a public IP the less clients can connect the better.

Order matters in your sshd configuration, and the first obtained value wins. Are there any Include directives prior to your attempt to change the crypto settings?
On my Fedora system, /etc/ssh/sshd_config starts with Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf, and that ultimately includes /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config which sets accepted ciphers, macs, etc. Anything I put in sshd_config itself would be ignored if it came after that Include line.
